# Can I use different file name rather than hibernate.cfg.xml in my application

Tags: hibernate

Can I use different file name of hibernate rather than hibernate.cfg.xml in my application where I am using Hibernate as a ORM Framework?

```
configuration = new Configuration();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure("MyFileName.cfg.xml")
        .buildSessionFactory();
```

I want to use a different file name in my application ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. In that case, it has to be explicitly specified as you are doing in the code above. If the file is in classpath, you need not have the slash in front of the file name.

```
configuration = new Configuration();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure("MyFileName.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Here, MyFileName.cfg.xml should be present in the classpath.

Comment: how can we do that ?? can you write a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the name of the default properties file (`hibernate.properties`) besides the default name of the configuration file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`), you need to put them in the resource folder. Then, you can force Hibernate to use them in this manner:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myhibernate.properties"));
        configuration.addProperties(properties);

        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myhibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

`myhibernate.properties`:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.pool_size=1
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

`myhibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <mapping class = "tech.procode.Student"/>


  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Let me shed some light on *why* part.

If we will look into `Hibernate`'s Configuration class, apart from other code, we will also see this:

```java
public class Configuration {
    
    //...

    public Configuration configure() throws HibernateException {
        return configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.DEFAULT_CFG_RESOURCE_NAME );
    }

    //...

    public Configuration configure(String resource) throws HibernateException {
        standardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(resource);
        properties.putAll(standardServiceRegistryBuilder.getSettings());
        return this;
    }

}
```

and the value of `DEFAULT_CFG_RESOURCE_NAME` in `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` is:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_CFG_RESOURCE_NAME = "hibernate.cfg.xml";
```

So, Hibernate has a hard-coded name for the xml configuration file, which it considers as a default name, if no custom argument is provided to the `.configure()` method, and that name is `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

That is why, `new Configuration().configure()` call, without any argument, will attempt to load `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

However, of course, you can use your custom name for that configuration, but in this case, you call another, overloaded method, that accepts and consumes `resource` argument.

So:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("my-hibernate-config.xml");
```

will also work identically.